# Authentication Filter not working with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I am developing an application with Spring Boot + spring security. For the same i have defined a filter as.

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/authtoken").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/authenticate**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/authfailure").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(tokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(accessFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider)
            .antMatcher("/**").exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

}
```

Where tokenFilter is an instance of AuthTokenFilter(class that has code for authentication and is injected to using @inject) .

AuthTokenFilter implements methods of Filter interface as.

```
 public class AuthTokenFilter implements Filter {
 ServletContext sc ;
 @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
    sc = fc.getServletContext();
   }

  @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain  fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
 ------- 
 ------- 
 }
```

My issue is when I run the app using SpringBoot , it runs fine. But when I create a war out of it and run the same in a tomcat, neither the init nor the doFilter are invoked for the request. Hence it returns unauthorized.

Same happens for accessFilter.

Does anyone know the reason behind this behavior? or What changes I need to make to get my app working on tomcat?

Comment: I would say because your whole security setup is wrong. I suspect due to the fact that it is a `Filter` and you are registering it as a `@Bean` when running in embedded mode the filter gets called by the servlet container and not Spring Security. I doubt that the latter is even working.

Comment: Yeah @M.Deinum , i understand that it might not be the best way of doing it. Can you suggest me, on making this better ?

Comment: For starters remove the `@Named` annotation so that it isn't picked up and added to the normal filter chain. If you have a `@Bean` method to create the filter remove that as well. Just create an instance and register it with the spring security filter chain. I suspect it then starts failing in both cases...

Answer (score 0):

What Tomcat version you use?

I am not sure, but try this:

In declaration of class AuthTokenFilter, add the anotation @Component

I have one project with filter and only write:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter ...
```

.

Comment: Thanks @Jorge, That may not work I am already using @ Named annotation. I am using tomcat 8 with Java 8.

Comment: @biraj use SpringBootServletInitializer?

Comment: :yeah I am using that, else wont create a deployable war.

Comment: I edited, but i don't have more idea... sorry. Can you give more specific code?